# Multiple Input() in one line Python

Tags: python, input

I was wondering if its possible to write instead of many variables and inputs in different lines of code, write all in one sentence.

Usually I've seen and wrote like this:

```
VARIABLE1 = input(var1)
VARIABLE2 = input(var2)
print(var1 + var2)
```

So the prompt will ask you to write 2 values in diferent sentences, because its been written that way. But is it possible to have the same output in the prompt (asking values in diferent senteces) making just one `input()`?

I've been reading about `.split()`, `map()` and lists, but the output is that the values have to be written in one sentence.

Comment: Can you share sample inputs and what you would expect as an output or to which variables which parts of the singular input string you describe should be assigned? Can you also share your attempt at meeting the requirement you describe as a [mre], along with an explanation as to how your attempt did not meet your requirements? See [ask]

Comment: Did you try `print(input(var1) + input(var2))`? Is there a specific way its behavior differs from what you want or expect? (BTW, your _title_ says "multiple input() in one line", but your text says "just one input()"; those are two different/contradictory requests; the latter might be `''.join([input(prompt) for prompt in [var1, var2])`).

Comment: _However_, writing for terseness over readability and maintainability is frowned on in Python -- see [PEP-20](https://peps.python.org/pep-0020/) -- perhaps to the point where one might argue that a request for a one liner _without any practical reason given_ falls afoul of our rule that questions should be practical as well as answerable.

Comment: Sorry I couldn't express myself correctly. This is more a curiosity than an actual problem or error.

Comment: I was asking if it was possible to write
var1,var2,var3,var4 = input('Write your variable1->') + input('Write your variable2->') + input('Write your variable3->') +input('Write your variable4->')

And then the output of the prompt would say

Write your variable1-> var
Write your variable2-> var2
Write your variable3-> var3
Write your variable4-> var4

Comment: Don't you mean `print(VARIABLE1 + VARIABLE2)`? Your code prints the prompts again, not the responses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use tuple assignment:

```
name, age = input('What is your name? '), int(input('How old are you? '))
```

Comment: @Vri But please don't use it in a real program.

Comment: @Matthias That's how I feel when I see multi-variable initializations like `var1, var2 = 123, 456`